# Showing your cards after your opponent has mucked his

Tags: texas-hold-em, muck, showdown

I was recently heads up in a poker game. My opponent bet, and I called. My opponent immediately said nice call and mucked his cards. He then demanded that I show him my hand. I refused because in my opinion as soon as he mucked his cards he was no longer in the hand. If he had held his cards I would have gladly shown him mine but he immediately threw his cards  away. 
Please tell me who was correct in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You only have to show your hand when you are up against at least one other, still not mucked hand and you want to claim the pot. You never have to show your cards otherwise.

In this case you are the only one eligible for the pot and thus you don't have to show your hand.

It is funny that he demands you to show your hand. The person that made the last aggressive move (bet, raise) has to show his hand first. He didn't, so you certainly don't have to.

Comment: Thank you. I believed I was correct. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: Did anybody noticed that the villain's request is, actually, a huge tell?

Comment: I did not. What is the tell?

Comment: @Bogdan Doicin .

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans a tell is a clue which is given by the opponent, a clue about his hand strength . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tell_(poker)

Comment: "In this case you are the only one eligible for the pot and thus you don't have to show your hand." this is not true at showdown, at least not according to the current TDA rules. Technically speaking both players at showdown are obligated to show their hands. Just because this rule is not followed doesn't mean it's not in place.

House rules can always overrule this for sure, but the general rule for tournaments is that you have to show your hand at showdown, especially if you want to claim the pot.

Comment: @Jonast92 well you sure have a point. But the opponent certainly has to show too. If he does not, I for sure will not show my hand.

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans That's up to you. You can however end up not winning the pot if you muck your cards. Even if villain does so first.

Comment: @Jonast92 then who gets the chips? They must be given to someone.